# "Call to undefined function odbc_exec()" error connecting to Access database on Linux PHP server

Tags: php, ms-access, webserver, adodb

I am getting the folowing error trying to run a test query on an Access Database
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_exec() in /home/ratpackc/public_html/Preview/ADOdb/drivers/adodb-odbc.inc.php on line 536"

I downloaded (from http://adodb.sourceforge.net) and unzipped the entire contents of the adodb514.zip into a folder I named ADOdb.
I am running the following test code:

```
<?PHP

include("ADOdb/adodb.inc.php");

$RecCount = 0;

$DBPath = realpath("TheData/TheData.mdb");
echo  $DBPath . " <br />" . chr(13);

$DBConn =& ADONewConnection('access');
$DSN = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$DBPath;";

$DBConn->Connect($DSN);

$SqlStr = "SELECT TheDate FROM SomeTable ";
echo  $SqlStr . " <br />" . chr(13);

$DBConn->debug = true;
if ($DBConn->Execute($SqlStr) === false) print ErrorMsg();

$RS = $DBConn->Execute($SqlStr);

if (!$RS)
echo $DBConn->ErrorMsg();
else
while (!$RS->EOF)
{
$RecCount++;
echo $RS->fields("TheDate")." <br />" . chr(13);
$RS->MoveNext();
}

$RS->Close();
$DBConn->Close();

echo "<hr />" . chr(13);
echo $RecCount." <br />" . chr(13);

?>
```

You can see the actual results of this code at http://www.rat-pack.com/Preview/DBTest.php

If it helps at all here is my phpinfo http://www.rat-pack.com/Preview/phpinfo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sample file that contains:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

If you don't see the odbc extension loaded you'll need to load it in your php.ini or recompile with odbc support.

Comment: I'm guessing it's something you have to have to be on the server to do. If so, I'll have to try to get my hosting company to enable it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe because you don't have odbc installed or setup with php ?

Comment: Because sometimes we need to interface with existing systems that aren't MySQL.